# why is event.button not working properly with mousedown event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

Here's a picture of the error:

[image]

I'm trying to get the event.button to do something when someone left clicks on a image, but the event.button is not working for me. I don't know why I'm getting this error. Is it saying that my event parameter is undefined in my Javascript code, or is it saying that buttons is undefined? I don't understand, I could use some help with this question. I set event.buttons equal to x and if x == 1 which means if someone left clicks one of images then something happens.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function dontShowDots(event) {
    var x = event.buttons;
    if (x == 1) {
        arrayDots[0].style.display = "none";
        arrayDots[1].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="empty-squares"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="50px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty-squares"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="50px" width="60px"></div>
            <div id="square1"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" onclick="showDots()" height="75px" width="75px"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="container1">
            <div class="empty-squares"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="50px" width="50px"></div>
            <div class="empty-squares"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="50px" width="50px"></div>   
            <div id="square2"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" onmousedown="dontShowDots()" onclick="showDots2()" height="75px" width="75px"></div>
        </div>           
            
        
        <script src="interactive.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

css code:

```
.empty-squares img {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
onmousedown="dontShowDots(event)"
```

Comment: `try` is not a helpful explanation why it is necessary to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
onmousedown="dontShowDots(event)"
```

One can access the current event through `window.event`. Just using `event` is implicitly accessing `window.event`.

Comment: Why should there be a `$` in front of `event`?

Comment: `$event` is something you can find in angular or vue. But it’s nothing that exists in vanilla javascript. Using `$event` will result in an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined` error.

Comment: Updated answer, @t.niese I agree